# Filter out permutations that only match words from dictionary

Tags: c++

I have the following method, it list all the possible permutations of the user input:

The output of this code would be for the word god (word is in dictionary)

```
dgo
dog
gdo
god
odg
ogd
```

I goal is to filter out the results which don't match words from my dictionary..

```
dog
god
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work just fine:

```
do {
  if (searchWord(input)) {
    cout << input << endl;
  }
} while (next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));
```

Comment: @user2881555 What has debugging told you? Why does `searchWord()` return a null pointer if the word is in the dictionary?

Comment: returns null if the word the user has inputted is not in the dictionary. It compiles fine, but when I input a word and search, it doesn't print the permutations.

Comment: @user2881555 I mean, when you use a debugger and step into `searchWord(input)` when `input` reaches a value which *is* in the dictionary, why does it return null? What has this debugging told you?

Comment: @user2881555 You claim `"dog"` and `"god"` is in the dictionary. Looking at your code on ideone, `Dictionary::searchWord()` should return a non-null pointer if the word is there. Why does it return null when `input` reaches the permutations `"god"` and `"dog"`? Either they are not in the dictionary (as you claim they are), or the function doesn't return what it should. Find out why. That's basic debugging, really.

Comment: Im 100% sure the words exist. So it must be an error with the returning?

Comment: If I change `return NULL;` It crashes when I search for a word not in the dictionary.

Comment: @user2881555 Try to isolate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) out of your code (= remove everything not needed to reproduce the bad permutation behaviour), and add it to the question along with a sample input file. Try to avoid non-standard stuff like `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: Oh I feel like an idiot, I changed around something in my main method and it wasn't calling the permutation method correctly., anyway it's working now. Its saying `word not in dictionary` for jumbled letters and words that are display they're displaying fine, I just need to filter out the permutation so `word not in dictionary` isnt displayed.

Comment: @user2881555 Well, that should be a trivial fix of making the output from `searchWord()` optional - perhaps give it an extra boolean parameter with a default argument?